# How to scale multi tenant application for almost 2000 tenants

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I want to create a multi tenant application. How to scale the db or partition because tenants will be more than 2000.

Is it correct to have individual db for each tenant.
Is it correct to split tenants by geographical region.Reporting will be a problem to get from individual tenant or generatinh report across multiple tenants.

Answer (score 0):

This question may be off topic as too opinion based but here's a few things to note about DocumentDB:

1. You are limited to 5 databases by default.
2. Pricing is by collection, so it would be very costly to partition tenants into their own collection.

The common way to do this is to have a field with tenantID on each document and put all of your tenants into one collection. You may be surprised how much data fits in one collection and you can spill-over to a new collection when one fills up or you are constantly exceeding your resource unit limit.